# float a form to right in bootstrap 2 column but not inline

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Hi I am trying to get a form to be 2 column what i mean is that the form goes al way to bottom then wraps the secondary form to the right its so that a partner of a joint applicant can enter his or her details to match that on a joint application.

But as you see the markup i have which is bootstrap 3 is just producing one continues form where it says partner details i need it to float to the right.

https://snag.gy/u1EWX4.jpg

But as you can see it displaying the form full screen not even 2 colum i need it to split where i say partner details in the code so that firtname surname fields line up correctly its basically a duplication of the fields on left should be on right.

Where the text Partner Details is in the code markup is where I need it to float right you will see I even tried a div with float right but did not work as intedned

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uptPanelPersonalDetails" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Is Joint Application</label>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="checkbox">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadCheckBox AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsJointApplication_CheckedChanged" Skin="Bootstrap" ID="chkIsJointApplication" runat="server"></telerik:RadCheckBox>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">IVA Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtIVACode" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                            First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtMiddle" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                            Surname</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSurname" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Saluatation</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdSaluation" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ailases</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAilases" CssClass="form-control" Width="40%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Marital Status</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdMartialStatus" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Introducer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="txtIntroducerName" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 1</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 2</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddressLine2" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">City</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCity" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Post Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPostCode" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">County</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="dpCounty" CssClass="form-group-lg" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="dpCountry" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Of Birth</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdDob" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAge" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Home Tel NO.</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeTelNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Work Tel No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtWorkTelNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Fax No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFaxNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Mobile No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtMobileNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtBestTimeToCall" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Prefered Contact Method</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdPreferedContactMethod" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Gender</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdGender" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="float: right;">
                        Partner Details

            <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                                First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox2" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                                Surname</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox3" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Saluatation</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ailases</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox4" CssClass="form-control" Width="40%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Marital Status</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Introducer Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox3" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox5" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox6" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox7" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Post Code</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox8" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">County</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox4" CssClass="form-group-lg" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox5" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Of Birth</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox9" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Home Tel NO.</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox10" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Work Tel No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox11" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Fax No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox12" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Mobile No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox13" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox14" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Prefered Contact Method</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox6" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox15" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Gender</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox7" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Note 1**
I had tried the method as mention below but im afriad I am still having the same results.

[image]

Comment: Apply `pull-right` class to the div

Comment: @MairajAhmad Hi to which class the class beside partner text ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another grid layout to do so. See the plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5k9H0yXKOn5MrkVjs6KV?p=preview).

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <label class="checkbox">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadCheckBox AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsJointApplication_CheckedChanged" Skin="Bootstrap" ID="chkIsJointApplication" runat="server"></telerik:RadCheckBox>
                        </label>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">IVA Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtIVACode" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                        First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtMiddle" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                        Surname</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSurname" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Saluatation</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdSaluation" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ailases</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAilases" CssClass="form-control" Width="40%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Marital Status</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdMartialStatus" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Introducer Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="txtIntroducerName" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 1</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddressLine2" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">City</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCity" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Post Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPostCode" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">County</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="dpCounty" CssClass="form-group-lg" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="dpCountry" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Of Birth</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdDob" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAge" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Home Tel NO.</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtHomeTelNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Work Tel No</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtWorkTelNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Fax No</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFaxNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Mobile No</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtMobileNo" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtBestTimeToCall" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Prefered Contact Method</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdPreferedContactMethod" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Gender</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdGender" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          Partner Details

        <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                            First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox2" CssClass="form-control" Width="20%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                            Surname</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox3" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Saluatation</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ailases</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox4" CssClass="form-control" Width="40%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Marital Status</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Introducer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox3" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 1</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox5" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Address Line 2</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox6" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">City</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox7" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Post Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox8" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">County</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox4" CssClass="form-group-lg" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox5" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Of Birth</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox9" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Home Tel NO.</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox10" CssClass="form-group-lg" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Work Tel No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox11" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Fax No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox12" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Mobile No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox13" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox14" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Prefered Contact Method</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox6" Width="50%" CssClass="form-group-lg" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Best Time to Call</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox15" CssClass="form-group-lg" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Gender</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox7" Width="50%" Skin="Bootstrap" EmptyMessage="Please Select" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: May be you are not using proper grid layout, please provide some plunker code so that I can help you